# Create a goal in Google Analytics from the last two visited pages where the last one is goal destination url

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I have to calculate the conversion rate for an ecommerce website which had no defined goals for a long period of time. Aside that the success page had no distinct url than the order view page.

However I am able to identify a conversion by filtering the `order-view` pageviews  -
 where users are redirected after they place an order - by the traffic that came only from `shopping-cart` page.

Basically I will know an order was placed if the user that reached order view page came directly from the shopping cart page.

So my question is: can I create a goal in google analytics that will compute the conversion rate from these two steps starting with installing Google Analitycs?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "starting with installing Google Analytics"? This is likely something you'll need to use some kind of session storage, cookie, or referrer check on the code-side (not within GA).

Comment: I meant from the moment we added ga tracking on our website. In the begining we had set any goals.